# Java: main running from console fails, not found main class

Tags: java, package

I am making some tests of java basics topics (imports and packages). I have this structure of folders

```
Example A \
    - main\
        -- Main.java
    - vehicle\
        - barcos\
            --Barco.java
        - aviones\
            --Avion.java
        - automovil\
            --Coche.java
```

**Barco.java**

```
package vehicle.barcos;

public class Barco{
    private String marca;
    public String getMarca(){
        return this.marca;
    }
}
```

**Avion.java**

```
package vehicle.aviones;

public class Avion{
    private String marca;
    public String getMarca(){
        return this.marca;
    }
}
```

**Coche.java**

```
package vehicle.automovil;

public class Coche{
    private String marca;
    public String getMarca(){
        return this.marca;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
package main;
import vehicle.barcos.Barco;
public class Main{  
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Barco barco = new Barco();
    }
}
```

I compiled all files (in the described order), when I run the main class, I am getting a message that says that can found the main class. Example A is the parent folder of main and vehicles

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\OCA8Examples\02 - Packcages and imports\Example A>java main\Main
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal main\Main

C:\Users\User\Desktop\OCA8Examples\02 - Packcages and imports\Example A>java -classpath "C:\Users\User\Desktop\OCA8Examples\02 - Packcages and imp
orts\ExampleA" main\Main
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal main\Main
```

Comment: Try "java main.Main" instead of "java main\Main".

Comment: This is not a compilation problem. Fix your title.

Comment: Great. @tsolakp worked :).

Comment: @EJP you are right, edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, thanks to [@tsolakp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812787/tsolakp).

I was running my main method on this way:

```
java main\Main (using "\" between folders, window's style)
```

But the correct way is the **package nomenclature**:

```
java main.Main
```